# Mongo C# driver - LINQ query with $elemMatch

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection with documents that look like this:

```
{'data': [{'Depth': 0.0, 'Value': 123.0},
          {'Depth': 0.5, 'Value': 456.0},
          {'Depth': 1.0, 'Value': 111.0},
          {'Depth': 1.5, 'Value': 321.0},
          {'Depth': 2.0, 'Value': 987.0},
          {'Depth': 2.5, 'Value': 666.0},
          ...
          {'Depth': 3.0, 'Value': 453.0}],
 'datatype': 'Sometype'
```

}

I want to execute queries that look like this:

```
curves = db.curvedata.findOne(
 {
  "datatype" : "Sometype",
  "data": {
   "$elemMatch": {
    "Depth" : { "$gt": 13000, "$lt": 13100 },
    "Value" : { "$gt": 20, "$lt": 100 } }}})
```

That is to find all curves within a Depth range and a Value range. This works fine - I'm running this with pymongo.

I have been trying to figure out how to use the Mongo DB C# driver to execute the same query using LINQ. This is what I have so far:

```
var curvedata = database.GetCollection("curvedata");
var query =
    from c in curvedata.AsQueryable()
    where c["datatype"] == "Sometype"
          && c["data"]["Depth"] > 13000
          && c["data"]["Depth"] < 13100
          && c["data"]["Value"] > 20
          && c["data"]["Value"] < 100
    select c;
```

This runs and returns a result - but a different result to the one I get with the pymongo query. That is, I get more documents with the C# query.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Is there something wrong with my translation to LINQ?

Comment: Is there any intersection between the python and c# results?  Also, are the C# results reasonable?  Do they conform to the query constraints?

Comment: I think you are missing the `Any` predicate, which is the analogue of the `$elemMatch` condition in the Pymongo query. I'm afraid I'm not familiar with C# or LINQ so I don't want to bungle trying to write a correct LINQ query, but check out the section "Any with Predicate" in the [LINQ tutorial](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/).